# ipad programming question

Tags: ipad, uiview

How to add a uitableview to uiview that already contain uitextboxes and uibutton

and initialize it with data

any suggestion please

Answer (score 1):

I have always found it easier to add additional views into the [`UITableViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableViewController) rather than nest a [`UITableView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableView) inside another view.

I use `UITableViewStyleGrouped` and then provide a customised `UIView` within the [`UITableViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate) for;

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```